# using user-defined datatype as a type for a function argument

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have the following datatypes defined:

```
datatype Arguments
  = IntPair of int * int
  | RealTriple of real * real * real
  | StringSingle of string;

datatype OutputArgs = IntNum of int | RealNum of real | Str of string;
```

and I try to create a function `MultiFunc: Arguments -> OutputArgs`:

```
fun MultiFunc(RealTriple (x, y, z)) : OutputArgs = RealNum ((x+y+z)/3.0)
  | MultiFunc(IntPair (x,y)) : OutputArgs = IntNum (x+y)
  | MultiFunc(StringSingle(s)) : OutputArgs = Str (implode(rev(explode(s))));
```

However when I call `MultiFunc(1.0,2.0,3.0)` I get the following error:

```
stdIn:588.1-588.23 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: Arguments
  operand:         real * real * real
  in expression:
    MultiFunc (1.0,2.0,3.0)
```

I.e. for some reason it doesn't recognize the input argument as being a `RealTriple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> MultiFunc(1.0,2.0,3.0)
> ```
>
> for some reason it doesn't recognize the input argument as being a `RealTriple`.

That's because the input isn't a `RealTriple`, but a 3-tuple of reals (`real * real * real`).

Try instead:

```
- MultiFunc (RealTriple (1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
> val it = RealNum 2.0 : OutputArgs
```

Here's how I'd write the function:

```
fun multiFunc (RealTriple (x, y, z)) = RealNum ((x+y+z)/3.0)
  | multiFunc (IntPair (x,y)) = IntNum (x+y)
  | multiFunc (StringSingle s) = Str (implode (rev (explode s)))
```

By having function names start with a lowercase, I distinguish them visually from value constructors like `RealTriple`. I don't write `: OutputArgs` but let the type of the function be inferred instead. And I omit redundant parentheses like `StringSingle(s)` or `explode(s)`: In many programming languages, function calls *must* have parentheses. In Standard ML, function application is achieved by juxtaposition of function on the left and argument on the right separated by whitespace. So `f x` is `f` being called on `x`, and `(f x) y` is "whatever `f x` returns, used as a function, on `y`."

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your triple into the corresponding data constructor to explain to the compiler that you mean something of type `Arguments` and not just a triple of real numbers:

```
MultiFunc (RealTriple (1.0,2.0,3.0))
```